# How to test an iOS Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, frameworks

I need to test an iOS Framework. I do not wish to test the UI. Is there any way to test just the Framework which would be used in the main Project?

Comment: Please add more detail to the question. What framework are you targeting? What aspects of its behavior do you want to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just plan to test logical stuff, you can create new Unittest target for framework by using XCTest.framework. It is available in Xcode 5 and above. There are also third-party unittest frameworks. Check this out http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-tutorial-for-ios-xcode-4-quick-start-guide